# How to manage any command access privileges on debian linux

Tags: linux, sudo, command

I am using Debian 7, and my desktop is xfce. I want to achieve managing any command on Linux. For example, executing `/usr/bin/xfce4-taskmanager` command would not require `sudo` privileges so any user can execute it. But I want to give privilege to user for `taskmanager` command. How can I achieve this?

I researched on Internet and found polkit (PolicyKit). Polkit has predefined actions and you can write rules for this actions. So I prepared custom action for `taskmanager` command. When I had executed `pkexec /usr/bin/xfce4-taskmanager` on console, I saw the message which I prepared before, but it is not solving my problem. I don't want to use `pkexec`.

I saw an action class prepared for `gparted` command. When I click gparted menu item from desktop with normal user, it is not opening because normal user does not have privileges. I changed access privilege and clicked again, and `gparted` opened successfully.

How can I write action like `gparted`? There is no documentation enough. Or is there another way to achieve this? Can I give `sudo` privilege to a command which is not have `sudo` privilege?

Comment: I did not fully understand, what you want to achieve. However, I think setuid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) might be worth looking at. Note, that this can be a security issue and you should know what you're doing when you want to use it.

Comment: Thnks for reply Stephan. My first aim is running polkit (PolicyKit) truly. This link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit says create an action, and this action id will send to DBus, then what will happen ? Here https://github.com/herzi/polkit-dbus-example an example of usage with dbus but he creates own command. My question is how can create a custom polkit action for  already available command on system and how can I manage it user-based.